# starter physical robot base recommendations?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, pioneer-3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for graduating from simulator to actual physical hardware with ROS support. Could anyone please recommend popular (and cheaper) options for a base? I want to get a base where I could implement and experiment slam/navstack.

Pioneer P3 DX (USD 4K) and Turtlebot (USD 2K) are on expensive side for individual starter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273085/starter-physical-robot-base-recommendations?/) by [hmrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32258/hmrobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-16**:
I'm not sure, but I feel this is more suitable for some discussion (as there isn't any single answer that is *the* answer). Perhaps a post on `discourse.ros.org` would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about the Trutlebot3 burguer? It is about $600

Some useful links:

http://www.robotis.us/turtlebot-3/

http://turtlebot3.robotis.com/en/latest/

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hmrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32258/hmrobo/) on 2017-10-15**:
Thanks, Martin. That is interesting but still on pre-order/nov delivery currently. Wondering if that's the cheapest or are there any other options including DIY.